# gSOAP with OPC XML-DA add attribute

Tags: c++, xml, wsdl, gsoap, opc

I'm trying to develop a soap client that will access data over the OPC XML-DA specification: [Here](http://www.opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=231&CN=KEY&CI=278&CU=97)

I've used the tools provided by gSOAP to generate the gSOAP header file from the OPC Foundations WSDL. (Relevant parts below)

I can't seem to get gSOAP to properly add an attribute to the  tag. (See Output section below). Is there a builtin way to do this, or will the WSDL/gSOAP header need to be modified?

WSDL extract:

```
<s:complexType name="ItemValue">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DiagnosticInfo" type="s:string" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Quality" type="s0:OPCQuality" />
</s:sequence>
<s:attribute name="ValueTypeQualifier" type="s:QName" />
<s:attribute name="ItemPath" type="s:string" />
<s:attribute name="ItemName" type="s:string" />
<s:attribute name="ClientItemHandle" type="s:string" />
<s:attribute name="Timestamp" type="s:dateTime" />
<s:attribute name="ResultID" type="s:QName" />
</s:complexType>
```

Generated gSOAP header

```
class ns1__ItemValue
{ public:
/// Element DiagnosticInfo of type xs:string.
    char*                                DiagnosticInfo                 0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Element 'Value' has no type or ref: assuming XML content.
    _XML                                 Value                          0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Element Quality of type "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/":OPCQuality.
    ns1__OPCQuality*                     Quality                        0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Attribute ValueTypeQualifier of type xs:QName.
   @_QName                               ValueTypeQualifier             0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ItemPath of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ItemPath                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ItemName of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ItemName                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ClientItemHandle of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ClientItemHandle               0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute Timestamp of type xs:dateTime.
   @time_t*                              Timestamp                      0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ResultID of type xs:QName.
   @_QName                               ResultID                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// A handle to the soap struct that manages this instance (automatically set)
    struct soap                         *soap                          ;
};
```

Generated Code

```
class SOAP_CMAC ns1__ItemValue
{
public:
    char *DiagnosticInfo;   /* optional element of type xsd:string */
    char *Value;    /* optional element of type xsd:anyType */
    class ns1__OPCQuality *Quality; /* optional element of type ns1:OPCQuality */
    char *ValueTypeQualifier;   /* optional attribute */
    char *ItemPath; /* optional attribute */
    char *ItemName; /* optional attribute */
    char *ClientItemHandle; /* optional attribute */
    time_t *Timestamp;  /* optional attribute */
    char *ResultID; /* optional attribute */
    struct soap *soap;  /* transient */
public:
    virtual int soap_type() const { return 18; } /* = unique id SOAP_TYPE_ns1__ItemValue */
    virtual void soap_default(struct soap*);
    virtual void soap_serialize(struct soap*) const;
    virtual int soap_put(struct soap*, const char*, const char*) const;
    virtual int soap_out(struct soap*, const char*, int, const char*) const;
    virtual void *soap_get(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
    virtual void *soap_in(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
             ns1__ItemValue() : DiagnosticInfo(NULL), Value(NULL), Quality(NULL), ValueTypeQualifier(NULL), ItemPath(NULL), ItemName(NULL), ClientItemHandle(NULL), Timestamp(NULL), ResultID(NULL), soap(NULL) { }
    virtual ~ns1__ItemValue() { }
};
```

Output

```
<ns1:Items
    ClientItemHandle="Channel1.Device1"
    ItemName="Channel_1.Device_1.Tag_1"
    ValueTypeQualifier="xsd:unsignedInt">
    <Value
        xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/">
        5
    </Value>
</ns1:Items>
```

Needed Output

```
<ns1:Items
    ClientItemHandle="Channel1.Device1"
    ItemName="Channel_1.Device_1.Tag_1"
    ValueTypeQualifier="xsd:unsignedInt">
    <Value
        xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/"
        xsi:Type="xsd:unsignedInt">
        5
    </Value>
</ns1:Items>
```

Output means the XML that is generated and sent over the wire to the remote server.

Comment: How do you set the value of the <Value> element in code?

Comment: In fact, <Value> is of type xsd:anyType, and I do not see how it will have another type definition.. For me the needed output seems kind of not so valid... Can you explain why do you want the output to be in the specified format?

Comment: In testing, my application would only communicate with some xml-opc-da servers. I compared the packets from my app, and a demo client from the OPC foundation.... th only change between the packets was that they had xsi:type="xsd:unsignedint" as an attribute to the value tag.

Comment: We've tried adding the -t to the soapcpp2.exe when we run our prebuild step but that just seems to add type information to complex types an not primitives.

Comment: Oops. I missed your first question. We have a reference to the ItemValue, so its just a matter of passing in a character array. ItemValueRef->Value = "0";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tisho, thanks for your input.

It turns out that the WSDL provided by the OPC Foundation lacked to specify a type on the value element. Our solution was to add a type of s:anyType, this allowed us to use polymorphic types such as:
xsd_*unsignedInt

xsd*_string
xsd__anyType

Since all of the types inherited from xsd__anyType, and a virtual soap_type function was included, we can use any of the types, and store them in the value, then gSOAP magically uses the soap_type to figure out what type the var is.

Relevant portion of the OPC Foundation's WSDL Modified:

```
<s:complexType name="ItemValue">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DiagnosticInfo" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:anyType"/> <!-- Here -->
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Quality" type="s0:OPCQuality"/>
  </s:sequence>
  <s:attribute name="ValueTypeQualifier" type="s:QName"/>
  <s:attribute name="ItemPath" type="s:string"/>
  <s:attribute name="ItemName" type="s:string"/>
  <s:attribute name="ClientItemHandle" type="s:string"/>
  <s:attribute name="Timestamp" type="s:dateTime"/>
  <s:attribute name="ResultID" type="s:QName"/>
</s:complexType>
```

Here's the new gSOAP generated header

```
class ns1__ItemValue : public xsd__anyType
{ public:
/// Element DiagnosticInfo of type xs:string.
    char*                                DiagnosticInfo                 0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Element Value of type xs:anyType.
    xsd__anyType*                        Value                          0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Element Quality of type "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/":OPCQuality.
    ns1__OPCQuality*                     Quality                        0;  ///< Optional element.
/// Attribute ValueTypeQualifier of type xs:QName.
   @_QName                               ValueTypeQualifier             0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ItemPath of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ItemPath                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ItemName of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ItemName                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ClientItemHandle of type xs:string.
   @char*                                ClientItemHandle               0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute Timestamp of type xs:dateTime.
   @time_t*                              Timestamp                      0;  ///< Optional attribute.
/// Attribute ResultID of type xs:QName.
   @_QName                               ResultID                       0;  ///< Optional attribute.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might be of help. I cannot test it right now, so it is just a suggestion. Look at 'Void pointers': http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc11.9

```
struct myStruct 
{ 
   int __type; // the SOAP_TYPE pointed to by p 
   void *p; 
};
```

As I understand from docs, this is used to serialize anything, with specifying it's type.
So it might work to replace the _XML type of the Value element with this struct.
Then you just have to set the __type attribute with the corresponding value:

```
struct ns1_Value {
   int __type; // the SOAP_TYPE pointed to by p 
   void *p; 
}
struct ns1_Value value; 
int n; 
value.p = &n; 
value.__type = SOAP_TYPE_int;
```

Another way to solve the problem could be to serialize raw xml instead of the <Value> element... Or to think of some xs:element that extends xs:anyType, but defines a xs:type..
Actually gSoap is a cool product, but to get the best of it you need to learn how to hack it..